# A question about the projection function

Tags: functions

Let $p:A\times B\to. A$

$p(x,y)=x$

The projection function *$p$* is clearly subjective. I want to know if it is bijective? The projective function suspiciously looks like $1_A(x)=x$

Comment: I corrected my mistake. It should be A

Answer (score 2):

If $|A|>1$ then we have two $a\ne a'$.

Since $p(a,x) = p(a',x)=x$ we see it is not injective and so it is...?

Comment: It is not bijective and can’t be an isomorphism .If it was I could use it in a theorem